# Can I travel to Germany by train with a "Récépissé de demande de carte de séjour" from France?

Tags: visas, schengen

My **"Récépissé de demande de carte de séjour"** says this on it:

> ((a demande la délivrance d'un premier titre de sejour portant la mention passport talent ce récépissé n'est pas valable qu'accompagne du document N° xxxx justifiant de l'identite de son titulaire exercise d'une activite salaire))

Can I travel to Germany **by train** for 2 days and come back to France?

Also, it might be beneficiary to mention that I am a Muslim Egyptian girl and I am wearing a hijab.

Comment: The French text on the (receipt for request of Residence Permit):

(She has requested the issuance of a first residence permit bearing the mentioned passport talent 
this receipt is not valid unless accompanied by the document N ° xxxx justifying the identity of its holder
exercise of a wage activity))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a friend who travelled from France to Amsterdam by bus with her récépissé and she had no problems. My husband has also applied for visas (and then travelled abroad) using his récépissé in the past. I hope this reassures you.

Comment: According to https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F15763, it depends on the exact type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. was you friend's récépissé for a first time demand?

Comment: No it was for a non-EU student renewal titre de séjour.